# Tic-Tac-Toe Loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, control-flow

I am making a game of tic-tac toe in javascript. I have laid out some of what I believe to be the basic building blocks:

```
var board = [
            0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0
            ];
gameOn = true;
player1Move = true;
counter = 0;
player1 = [];
player2 = [];
var ask = console.log(prompt('where would you like to go?'));

var drawBoard = function(){
    console.log("   A " + (board[0]) + "| B " + (board[1]) + "| C " + (board[2]));
    console.log("  ------------- ");
    console.log("   D " + (board[3]) + "| E " + (board[4]) + "| F " + (board[5]));
    console.log("  ------------- ");
    console.log("   G " + (board[6]) + "| H " + (board[7]) + "| I " + (board[8]));
    console.log("  ------------- ");
};

var solutions = [
    (board[0] && board[1] && board[2]) || (board[3] && board[4] && board[5]) ||
    (board[6] && board[7] && board[8]) || (board[0] && board[3] && board[6]) ||
    (board[1] && board[4] && board[7]) || (board[2] && board[5] && board[8]) ||
    (board[0] && board[4] && board[8]) || (board[2] && board[4] && board[6])
];



while (gameOn === true){
// for loop for game logic
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 9; i++){
      if (player1Move === true) {
        player1.push(ask);
        drawBoard();
        player1Move = false;
      } else if (player1Move === false){
        player2.push(ask);
        drawBoard();
        player1Move = true;
      } else if ((player1 || player2) === solutions){
          gameOn = false;
          console.log((player1 || player2) + "wins!");
      } else {
        gameOn = false;
        console.log("Tie Game!");
      }
    }
}
```

I know that the syntax of my main loop is incorrect. Why can't I do what is currently written? If you had this existing code, what type of loop setup would you use to accomplish this? Sorry if this seems not specific enough, I am just lost in the logic of it all!

With this existing loop all I am trying to do is go through and prompt the 2 users 9 times(because maximum moves = 9) in total for now. Once that works than I will keep adding more game logic into it. Why can't I get the prompt to come up 9 times? The current result is that it prompts me once, prints out the board 9 times and false after all of it.

This just needs to work in a terminal window for now too by the way.

Comment: 1. `var ask = console.log(prompt('where would you like to go?'));` <- definitely wrong. 2. use `var`. always. 3. learn to use a debugger.

Comment: by debugger do you mean linter? or just reading errors that get kicked back?

Comment: I mean google: "nodejs debugger" (if you're using node) or google: "chrome/firefox/internet explorer/else debugger" if you're using chrome/firefox/ie...

Comment: The use of a "game loop" in JavaScript makes me think you need to do a lot more research on asynchronous programming, callbacks, and promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code as little as possible, but a few things are different, which I am explaining bit by bit.

```
var board = {
    A: null,
    B: null,
    C: null,
    D: null,
    E: null,
    F: null,
    G: null,
    H: null,
    I: null
};

gameOn = true;
player1Move = true;

var drawBoard = function(){
    console.log("   A " + (board.A || '') + "| B " + (board.B || '') + "| C " + (board.C || ''));
    console.log("  ------------- ");
    console.log("   D " + (board.D || '') + "| E " + (board.E || '') + "| F " + (board.F || ''));
    console.log("  ------------- ");
    console.log("   G " + (board.G || '') + "| H " + (board.H || '') + "| I " + (board.I || ''));
    console.log("  ------------- ");
};

var solutions = function() {
    return (board.A && (board.A == board.B && board.A == board.C))
        || (board.D && (board.D == board.E && board.D == board.F))
        || (board.G && (board.G == board.H && board.G == board.I));
};

drawBoard();
var currentPlayer;

while (gameOn === true){
// for loop for game logic
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 9; i++){
        if (solutions()){
            console.log(currentPlayer + " wins!");
            gameOn = false;
            break;
         }
        //else {
        //    gameOn = false;
        //    console.log("Tie Game!");
        //}
        currentPlayer = 'Player 1';
        if(!player1Move)
            currentPlayer = 'Player 2';

        var ask = prompt(currentPlayer + ': where would you like to go (A or B or C or ..)?');
        if(ask == 'exit') {
            gameOn = false;
            break;
        }

        if (player1Move === true) {
            //player1.push(ask);
            board[ask] = 'X';
            drawBoard();
            player1Move = false;
        } else if (player1Move === false){
            board[ask] = 'O';
            drawBoard();
            player1Move = true;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not completely finished, but then that's something you can do afterwards, and probably you didn't want me to do it all for you.

This all works in a Chrome console.

There were a couple of basic things that were holding you back:

1. `var ask = console.log(prompt('where would you like to go?'));` should be `var ask = prompt(currentPlayer + ': where would you like to go?');` - your version was filling `ask` with null.
2. This prompt was also in the wrong place: it needs to be in the loop, and after drawBoard(), so that the player has something to look at.
3. I've changed the board from an array into an object, so that player answers like 'A' refer directly to the object fields. And that way the player arrays could be removed.
4. The `solutions()` function needs completing, as you can see, and there may be a neater way of doing this.
5. I added the possibility of writing 'exit' in the prompt, otherwise there's no way of exiting the game early.
6. I didn't finish the 'Tie game!' code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand the global object is, and what `window.prompt` is, and what `console.log` is in your context. It is *absolutely necessary* to get to know a debugger for your environment. In Chrome it's called Developer Tools.

`window.prompt` is not very useful in code sandboxes like jsfiddle, or the Stack overflow bulit-in ones. I suggest using HTML for your user interface.

```
function init() {
    trapForm();
    trapInput();
    toggleCurrentUser();
    askUser();
}

var game = [
    [null,null,null],
    [null,null,null],
    [null,null,null]
];

var trapInput = function() {
    //  capture input and use to to create a play in the game
    document.querySelector('#go').addEventListener('click',function(ev) {

        var position = document.querySelector('#square').valueAsNumber;

        if (position < 10 && position > 0) {

            //  render X or O to the HTML
            var td = document.querySelectorAll('#t3 td')[position-1];
            td.innerHTML = currentUser;

            //  modify the corresponding game array
            var row = Math.floor( (position-1) / 3 );
            var col = ( (position+2) % 3) ;
            game[row][col] = currentUser;

            //  this helps us visualize what's happening
            debug(game);
            checkGameStatus();
            toggleCurrentUser();            

        } else {
            debug({"msg":"illegal move"});
        }

    });
};

var trapForm = function() {
    //  prevent form from submitting
    var f = document.querySelector('#f');
    f.addEventListener('submit',function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        trapInput();
    });
};
```

```js
;(function(window,document,undefined){
  "use strict";

  function init() {
      trapForm();
      trapInput();
      toggleCurrentUser();
      askUser();
  }

  var currentUser = 'Y';

  var toggleCurrentUser = function(){
      if (currentUser === 'X') {
       currentUser = 'Y';   
      } else {
          currentUser = 'X';
      }
      document.querySelector('#currentuser').value = currentUser;
  };

  var isVirginal = function(game) {
      return game.every(function(row) {
          return row.every(function(cell) { return (cell === null); });
      });
  };

  var isStaleMate = function(game){
      return game.every(function(row){
          return row.every(function(cell){
              return (cell === 'X' || cell === 'Y');
          });
      });
  };

  var horizontalWinner = function(game) {
      var r = false;
      return game.some(function(row){
          var firstletter = row[0];
          if (firstletter === null) {
              return false;
          } else {
              return row.every(function(cell){
                  return ( cell !== null && cell === firstletter);
              });            
          }
      });
  };

  var verticalWinner = function(game) {
      var r = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          if (game[0][i] === null) {
              continue;
          }
          if (game[0][i] === game[1][i] && game[1][i] === game[2][i]) {
              r = game[0][i];
              break;
          }
      };
      return r;
  };

  var diagonalWinner = function(game) {
      var r = false;
      if (game[0][0] !== null && (game[0][0] === game[1][1] === game[2][2])) {
          r = game[0][0];
      }
      if (game[0][2] !== null && (game[0][2] === game[1][1] === game[2][0])) {
          r = game[0][2];
      }    
      return r;
  };

  var checkGameStatus = function(){
      var r = 'unknown';
      if (isVirginal(game)) {
          r = 'Virginal Game';   
      } else {
          r = 'In Play';   
      }
      if (isStaleMate(game)) {
          r = 'Stale Mate';
      }
      if (diagonalWinner(game)){
          r = 'Diagonal Winner: ' + diagonalWinner(game);
      }
      if (verticalWinner(game)) {
          r = 'vertical Winner: ' + verticalWinner(game);
      }
      if (horizontalWinner(game)) {
          r = 'Horizontal Winner: ' + horizontalWinner(game);
      }
      document.querySelector('#status').value = r;
  };

  var debug = function(stuff) {
      document.querySelector('#debug').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(stuff);
  };

  var game = [
      [null,null,null],
      [null,null,null],
      [null,null,null]
  ];

  var trapInput = function() {
      // capture input and use to to create a play in the game
      document.querySelector('#go').addEventListener('click',function(ev) {

          var position = document.querySelector('#square').valueAsNumber;

          if (position < 10 && position > 0) {

              // render X or O to the HTML
              var td = document.querySelectorAll('#t3 td')[position-1];
              td.innerHTML = currentUser;

              // modify the corresponding game array
              var row = Math.floor( (position-1) / 3 );
              var col = ( (position+2) % 3) ;
              game[row][col] = currentUser;

              // this helps us visualize what's happening
              debug(game);
              checkGameStatus();
              toggleCurrentUser();            

          } else {
              debug({"msg":"illegal move"});
          }

      });
  };

  var trapForm = function() {
      // prevent form from submitting
      var f = document.querySelector('#f');
      f.addEventListener('submit',function(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
          trapInput();
      });
  };

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);

})(window,document);
```

```css
#t3 {
    font-family: "Courier New";
    font-size: xx-large;
}
#t3 td {
 border: 1px solid silver;
 width: 1em;
 height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

#f {
    position: relative;
}

#f label, input, button {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#f label, button {
    clear: left;
}

hr {
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form id="f">
    <label for="currentuser">Current User</label>
    <input type="text" readonly id="currentuser" name="currentuser" />
    <label for="square">What Square (1-9)?</label>
    <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="9" id="square" name="square" />
    <label for="status">Game Status</label>
    <input type="text" readonly id="status" name="status" value="Virgin Game" />
    <button type="button" id="go">make move</button>
</form>

<hr />

<table id="t3">
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<pre id="debug"></pre>
```